# Getting Error - Failed to Read Schema Document - JBPM

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xsd, jbpm

I am getting the following error while bootsrapping JBPM application in Tomcat container.  I am creating the Process XML using BPMN 2.0 Eclipse plugin.

`Failed to read schema document 'http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI-XMI', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsdchema>.`

Some googling suggested it is a bug with the Eclipse Plugin.  But I didn't find any solution so far.

Eventually the server is starting and the processes are kicking, but due to these warnings, the process is taking a lot of time, north of 3 hours.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue has been identified. The bottle neck was with http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524 namespace. There were several such namespaces included in the BPM XML file for XSD. But they weren't getting loaded. The root cause is an Eclipse plugin bug for BPMN2 plugin that generates incorrect XSD definitions in the XML file. By removing all XSD definitions except BPMN2.0.xsd it started correctly.

> I have cross posted this answer from another answer of mine.